# Change date format based on location javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the date format to show up differently depending on which country a user is in for example:
usa: M/d/yyyy
esp: dd/MM/yyyy

I am using moment.js and from looking around the docs I thought this would work:

```
business.day = moment('2019-10-02').format('L');
```

I changed my computer setting to be set in spain instead of the us but I am still getting a date in the standard us: 10/02/2019

I would like to get 02/10/2019

Comment: This may help: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: Did you change your computer date format or language? MomentJs uses navigator language such as ES-es.

Comment: I just changed the date. I will try the langue too.